# How to include a Double Variable in a String Variable in Java?

Tags: java, string, parsing, double

Say, for example, I have a double variable in Java:

```
double alpha = 3;
```

However, I wanted to create a String variable, including that Double Variable:

```
String beta = "Alpha has a value of " + alpha;
```

So that the output would be

```
//Output
Alpha has the value of 3
```

However, it will not let me do so, as it says the double value cannot be included in the string value.

As I am doing this for around 150 variables, I want to know how to do it the simplest and shortest way.

Thanks

Comment: You should put variable names in lowercase.

Comment: Double.toString(double value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Double.toString(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)).

```
String beta = "Alpha has a value of " + Double.toString(alpha);
```

Answer (score 4):

> I am doing this for around 150 variables

A common way of simplifying a repeated task is defining a helper method for it:

```
String description(String name, Object obj) {
    return name + " has a value of " + obj;
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
String beta = description("Alpha", alpha);
```

Doing this for 150 variables sounds suspicious - chances are, you have an opportunity to make an array. You can define an array of names, then pair them up with values, like this:

```
String[] names = new String[] {
    "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", ...
}
double[] values = new double[] {
    1.2, 3.4, 5.6, ...
}
for (int i = 0 ; i != names.length() ; i++) {
     System.out.println(description(names[i], values[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you need to convert a double to a string, use

```
Double.toString(double);
```

Where double is the name of the variable.